# Optimize MySQL query order the results in GROUP BY 3 Tables Count

Tags: mysql, optimization, count, group-by

I have the following query:

```
SELECT contry, count(contry) as 'N'
FROM user_ip_tmp 
GROUP BY contry
ORDER BY count(contry) DESC
LIMIT 40

SELECT iconOperation, count(iconOperation) as 'N'
FROM user_ip_tmp 
GROUP BY iconOperation
ORDER BY count(iconOperation) DESC
LIMIT 40

SELECT iconBrowser, count(iconBrowser) as 'N'
FROM user_ip_tmp 
GROUP BY iconBrowser
ORDER BY count(iconBrowser) DESC
LIMIT 40
```

And working properly
But the delirious cause Query took Large
Each query

```
Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 40 total, Query took 2.2857 sec)
```

**Meaning that the total of all queries up Query took 15.661 sec**

I want to **merge** all the rave in the queries one query

Final results appear as follows

[image]

Comment: read about [union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

Comment: Not needed union Query from one table user_ip_tmp

Answer (score 0):

If you mean for all 6 columns to appear together as one recordset where one row has the country and its count followed by the browser and its count followed by the os and its count, I don't see how that's possible at the moment. There doesn't seem to be any relationship between the sets that can be linked together apart from the table name which isn't much help. If you can, please establish the relationship among these queries :)

Comment: I expected that he may combine this query one